# Is this code thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns true if a submission by the same IP address has not been submitted in the past n minutes.     
'' </summary>
Protected Function EnforceMinTimeBetweenSubmissions(ByVal minTimeBetweenRequestsMinutes  as Integer) As Boolean       
    If minTimeBetweenRequestsMinutes = 0 Then
        Return True
    End If
    If Cache("submitted-requests") Is Nothing Then            
        Cache("submitted-requests") = New Dictionary(Of String, Date)
    End If
    ' Remove old requests. '
    Dim submittedRequests As Dictionary(Of String, Date) = CType(Cache("submitted-requests"), Dictionary(Of String, Date))
    Dim itemsToRemove = submittedRequests.Where(Function(s) s.Value < Now).Select(Function(s) s.Key).ToList
    For Each key As String In itemsToRemove
        submittedRequests.Remove(key)
    Next
    If submittedRequests.ContainsKey(Request.UserHostAddress) Then
        ' User has submitted a request in the past n minutes. '
        Return False
    Else            
        submittedRequests.Add(Request.UserHostAddress, Now.AddMinutes(minTimeBetweenRequestsMinutes))
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Web.Caching.Cache` class is thread-safe according to the MSDN documenation.  However, the documenation also shows an example where a read and a write are performed on the cache without locking. That cannot possibily be thread-safe since the write is dependent on the read. The code you posted basically looks like the example.  I definitely recommend putting a lock around the entire method.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>No. The ASP.NET Cache is not inherently thread-safe and it looks like you are creating objects in the Cache depending on whether they exist or not.</strike>

You need to lock the Cache when writing to it.

Let me word things a little differently. The code is, in fact, thread safe. The way you currently have it coded though could cause performance issues in multi-threaded situations.

In this case, multiple users would be running the same code simultaneously, theoretically accessing and modifying the same cache objects at the same time. As that scenario scales up, performance suffers.

Creating a lock will improve performance under heavy load (while imposing a slight overhead under light load) because you won't be fetching data neadlessly due to Caching issues.

Comment: I don't know. Without locking that entire method I can envision some pretty strange sequencing of events. Imagine two thread that both see Cache("submitted-request") as Nothing. They both create new dictionaries and the race is on to write it to the Cache. I am afraid there might be a subtle bug that causes the code to incorrectly identify if a user has a previously submitted request. I would have to trace things out in detail, but a quick glace makes me suspicious.

Comment: @Brian Gideon - That situation could easily be handled by a double check (checking to see if the cache object is null outside the lock, and then again inside the lock).